# Argparse combine --help directives

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am currently building an extension to an existing library that uses `argparse.ArgumentParser()` to ingest cli arguments, and have added my own `argparse.ArgumentParser()` using `parse_known_args()` to parse out the arguments I want to inject before passing the remaining arguments on to the existing library's implementation. I am doing this instead of adding the arguments to the underlying library so that if the underlying library changes, everything should still work.

However, when I pass in the `--help` flag my implementation of `argparse.ArgumentParser()` grabs that flag, prints out help for my injected arguments then breaks execution so it never gets to the help message for the underlying library.

I am having trouble figuring out if there's a way to combine the help directives for both `argparse.ArgumentParser()` implementations (if it's even possible), or how to ignore the help flag in my implementation. My added arguments are for debug only and are not vital to display to the end user of my extended library, so if there is a way to ignore the help flag in my implementation, that would be OK, while not ideal.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`add_help=False`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#add-help).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be an answer to your question.  add_help=False, but added to subcommands and subparsers.  [Python argparse - disable help for subcommands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356411/python-argparse-disable-help-for-subcommands)

Comment: Not quite, this is for use with subprocessors in argparse. However,  I do believe that changed my model to use subprocessors might be what I am looking for in "combining" the argparse implementations that are defined. I'm going to try that out.

Comment: let me know if it works.  that's what i had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `parents` parameter to the subsequent parsers. I've just posted an answer to a similar question here:

[Argparse: is it possible to combine help texts from multiple parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642018/argparse-is-it-possible-to-combine-help-texts-from-multiple-parsers/72201116#72201116)